# Unable to install web3-eth-ens while installing web3-version 35

Tags: web3js-v1.x

I had web3 ver 36. Due to an issue, I rolled back to ver 35 as follows -

`npm install -g web3@1.0.0-beta.35 --save`

Before this, I did `npm cache clear --force`. However, it looks like web3-eth-ens is never getting installed. I always see the following error:

```
> var Web3 = require('web3');
Error: Cannot find module 'web3-eth-ens'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

What is wrong here? I even tried doing: `npm install web3-eth-ens`, but that did not help either.